# Generate a global frame from a family of matrices in python

Tags: python, numpy

Unfortunately, when mapping numpy.linalg.eigh() to a smooth 1-parameter family of matrices (given by a list in sequential order), instead of a smooth 1-parameter family of eigenvectors, I get discontinuities in the eigenvectors as a function of the same parameter.

The technical term for a set of linearly-independent smooth vector fields is a **global frame**. I need to generate a global frame of eigenvectors from a 1-parameter family of matrices. Is there a python package that does this automatically and efficiently?

Comment: Are the discontinuities in the eigenvectors just a matter of a factor of -1 (i.e. the overall sign flips), or are you running into parameter values where an eigenvalue has multiplicity greater than 1?

Comment: Correct: the discontinuities are just complex phases (I'm dealing with complex matrices), so they have unit norm. I don't think there are degeneracies.